# Microsoft InfoPath 2010 or greater is required to use this feature

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I customized the custom list form using InfoPath Designer in SharePoint Online. I have InfoPath Designer 2013 installed on my machine.

Suddenly today when I try to click the button `Customize using InfoPath form` link in the ribbon, it says

> Microsoft InfoPath 2010 or greater is required to use this feature

I checked for Addons `SharepointOpenDocuments` and `SharePointOpenXMLDocuments`, both are enabled. [Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b93a51b2-02fc-4048-af36-9c5352409126/message-microsoft-infopath-2010-is-required-to-use-this-feature?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

Comment: coule you plesa check if SharePoint Publishing feature is active on both Site collection and site features...if not then enable it and try again

Comment: Yes Publishing feature is activated already.

Comment: Ok, check on more thing, open site in browser and Turn off the active x filtering.

Comment: I did turn off.. But it dint work. Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: After checking on all the settings in the IE and SharePoint Site Collection/Site Features, I tried to repair MS Office and that worked for me. Thank you for all the inputs

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the AddOn "SharePoint OpenDocuments Class" in IE browser.

To know how to enable use this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f613e52c-9cf4-4180-a69a-eaceb6e4f238/sharepoint-opendocuments-class-addon?forum=sharepointadminlegacy)

Comment: They are already enabled.